# JSESSIONID in javascript - How can Open Layers 3 obtain it?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I have created an Open Layers 3 Map which loads its tiles from my server, i dont transmit the user id, it's recognized server side, so the map does not work if there is not user logged in.

So far so good, everything working. If someone clicks on a feature in the map i would like to send some request to the server as well, also without sending the user id, cause there should be a session anyway. But if i send an AJAX request to the server, then the JSESSIONID will be missing from the request and i get a new session id every time i send a request.

I know this is due to HttpOnly flag, but what bugs me is, how can Open Layers have the JSESSIONID in its requests, but i dont get it for my own Ajax requests.

See also the picture for the difference:

-- GetTile is a request generated by Open Layers

-- GetStarMapData is a request generated by own written Ajax call

Both requests just access a servlet on the Server

[image]

Comment: You need to serve the HTML from your server instead of `file://`.

Comment: Yeah, i was just curious why it worked in open layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-origin XHR requests (the Origin in your screenshot indicates you are making one) only include cookies if you explicitly turn [credentials support](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute) on.

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

This will make it a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) so you will have to configure the server to correctly respond to OPTIONS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that was the problem - I guess it would have worked, if i had not tested the site on some local folder and instead loaded it from my test server as well then.